# Get Wordpress posts with images link

Tags: android, mysql, wordpress

I want to get wordpress posts with specific category and link of images.
As you know images links save to database in guid column, when `post_type = attachment`.
and `ID` of post and `post_parent` are the same.
Now I want to get posts and join guid column to same `ID`.
When I added Inner join to combine attachment and post, I got error!
Please help me, if you know the way that I can get post with specific category and images link of each post.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    wp_posts p,
    wp_postmeta m,
    wp_terms t,
    wp_term_taxonomy tt,
    wp_term_relationships tr,
    wp_terms t2,
    wp_term_taxonomy tt2,
    wp_term_relationships tr2
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p2
ON
    p.ID = p2.post_parent
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.ID = tr.object_id 
AND t.term_id = tt.term_id 
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
AND tt.term_id = t.term_id 
AND t.name = 'Fashion'
GROUP BY
    p.ID
ORDER BY
    id
DESC
```

```
MySQL said:

#1054 - Unknown column 'p.ID' in 'on clause'
```

[image]

Comment: Ditch the old school comma operator for the join operation, use the `JOIN` keyword instead. The comma syntax is still valid, for backwards compatibility with existing code, but there's no good reason new development should use the comma syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is due to mixing the old school comma syntax with the newer JOIN keyword.

Relevant excerpt from MySQL Reference Manual:

> `INNER JOIN` and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

---

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to ditch the old school syntax for the join operation, use the `JOIN` keyword instead.

(It's great that the comma syntax is still valid, to provide backwards compatibility with existing SQL. But there's no good reason new development should use the comma syntax.)

---

Aside from that, there's a couple of big rock issues that stick out to me.

Seems like there's a lot of join conditions missing

Using `*` for the SELECT list in development can be useful shortcut, but we usually list the expressions we need to return, especially if we want to return `id` column from multiple tables, where we like to assign a column alias to avid duplicate columns names.

Relying on the non-standard extension to GROUP BY (when `only_full_group_by` is omitted from `sql_mode` to return values from "some" row in the collapsed group

Those all look like serious problems to me.

We can re-write the OP query to use `JOIN` keyword in place of comma syntax, and relocating conditions to the `ON` clause, this highlights what looks like missing join conditions:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts p

  JOIN wp_postmeta m
 -- ON ???
  JOIN wp_terms t
    ON t.name = 'Fashion'
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
    ON tt.term_id   = t.term_id 
   AND tt.taxonomy   = 'category'
  JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
    ON tr.object_id = p.id
   AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
  JOIN wp_terms t2
  -- ON ???
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2
 -- ON ???
  JOIN wp_term_relationships tr2
 -- ON ??
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_posts AS p2
    ON p2.post_parent = p.id

 WHERE p.post_type =   'post' 
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'
 GROUP
    BY p.id
 ORDER
    BY p.id DESC
```

Where we are going to omit any join condition, and just match all rows to all other rows, then my preference is to include the (optional) `CROSS` keyword, as an aid the future reader, to signal that the omission of a join condition is by design, and not an oversight.